# unifying active directory usernames / logins by creating a trust relationship?

Tags: exchange-2010, single-sign-on, active-directory

I have a conceptual question:

I manage user accounts for local network access using Active Directory (let's call this network A). We use an external service provider for email accounts, who's also running Active Directory for account management (network B).

In this configuration, every user ends up with two usernames: one for the local network (A), and one for email (B). Let's call the usernames `DOMAIN_A\username` and `DOMAIN_B\username`.

I was wondering whether these usernames could be `unified` by creating a trust relationship between the two active directory servers? Is that possible? It seems to be right now, that the purpose of a AD trust relationship is only to allow users from network B to authenticate against their home AD while being on network A. Does a trust relationship also allow to `connect / map` AD accounts on different networks (different ADs), so that using a single username, will log the user into both network A and network B? That is, using `DOMAIN_A\username` as a long-in, I can login to both network A resources and network B resources? I this is indeed possible, how do you have to setup the mapping between `DOMAIN_A\username` and `DOMAIN_B\username`? The two ADs won't be able to guess which usernames belong to the same user.

**EDIT:** this [website](http://attackcomputerwiz.blogspot.de/2010/03/accessing-microsoft-exchange-email.html) might have the solution. However it is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link you posted may work, but you need to be clear on this:

**There is no such thing as merging / joining / combining / whatever Active Directory accounts** - this is the same whether on a single domain, single forest, multiple domains, multiple forests with trusts etc etc etc

In your case, an account on Network A is *always* mutually exclusive to an account on Network B - even if they were to share the same username.

It may help if you always think of the username in terms of "DOMAINA\Username" vs "DOMAINB\Username" - you should see now how these two will always be different.

With regards to Exchange, you have a mailbox belonging to DOMAINB\john.smith - by using that link, you're setting up permissions so that DOMAIN\smith.john can access the account. Just in the same way that, on a single domain, you may give a manager access to someone else e-mail.

Comment: thanks! so you are saying that despite the trust between ADs, a user would still need to use `DOMAINB\username` for email access and `DOMAINA\username` for local network access? So what I tried to solve (using one login for all services) won't be possibles, despite the trust?

Comment: @memyself Correct, but what you *can* do, is give one account permissions to the other accounts resources.

Comment: so in the end `DOMAINA\username` will be able to log into `DOMAINB\username`? that's great!